# PyModbus.server port 502 not open StartTcpServer

Tags: python, modbus

I am setting up a Modbus TCP server on my Linux PC. 
When i run the code below the port 502 is not open on my computer, when i check with nmap.

Anyone have experience with this?

https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/synchronous-server.html

```
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer

from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext

store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# initialize the server information
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# If you don't set this or any fields, they are defaulted to empty strings.
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName  = 'Pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl   = 'http://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName   = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.0'

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# run the server you want
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# Tcp:
StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=('localhost', 502))
```

Edit:
If i connect to the server with a client on the same computer, the server is working. If i close the server the client responds with port 502 closed.

Comment: Are you running the script as root? Low port numbers cannot be opened by non-root users in Unix.

Comment: Yes Fredrick, I am running the script as root $sudo python modbusserver.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'localhost'` string you give as the server's listening address in this call:

```
StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=('localhost', 502))
```

tells your server to listen for connections only from clients running on the same system as the server.  If you want your server to accept connections from other systems then pass an empty string `''` as the address instead of `'localhost'`.  The empty string tells the server to listen on all of this system's interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your replay @ottomeister, I did not know that. I used '0.0.0.0', and that worked to.